# How to change the default Apk Replace message?

Tags: android, apk, auto-update

I am using the below code for updating the apk for my application on the Login button. The code works as follows :

I have a text file in a folder on the server which maintains the apk version number and the apk also in the same folder. The apk first downloads the text file and then reads the contents in the file, if the version is greater than the current apk version it downloads the apk from the server and installs it. During the installation process i get dialog box as 
[image]

There is nothing that i have written in the code that will invoke this dialog box..Is it possible to change the message as **Update Application** instead of **Replace Application** ????? I am aware that this is a device generated message. But is there a possibility to change it??? Please help!!!

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: One way to overcome this would be to change the package name in either one of the .apk's. However then you are not essentially updating but replacing.

Comment: @ByzantineFailure i dont want to install another apk. The apk should be replaced but i just want to change the message of the dialog box.

Comment: That wont be possible then unfortunately. (under normal circumstances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change this message. It is part of Android framework and will pop up each time you install application with the same package id as already installed one (updating).